# Get parameter from url

Tags: ember.js

In my ember app a user can create a new project at the route '/#/pm/:program_id/projects/new' where ':program_id' is a variable that can change. A project belongs to a program, so every project I create needs that association. How do I access the program that the route was called with?

Edit for comment:

```
App.ProjectsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.createRecord 'project'

  deactivate: ->
    @currentModel.rollback()
```

-

```
App.ProjectsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  statuses: ["Active", "Attrited", "Dropped", "Completed"]
  actions:
    submit: ->
      project = @get('model')
      @get('model').save().then(@onCreate.bind(@), @onFail.bind(@))

  onCreate: ->
    @transitionToRoute('projects.index')

  onFail: ->
    console.log 'failure'
```

-

```
App.Router.map ->

  @resource 'su', ->
    @resource 'programs', ->
      @route 'new'
      @route 'edit', path: ':program_id/edit'

    @resource 'users', ->
      @route 'new'
      @route 'edit', path: ':user_id/edit'

    @resource 'availability', ->
      @resource 'availability.show', path: ':program_id', ->
        @route 'details', path: 'details/:user_id'

  @resource 'pm', path: 'pm/:program_id', ->
    @resource 'projects', ->
      @route 'new'
      @route 'edit', path: ':project_id/edit'
```

Comment: Will you show your router and associated routes.  More than likely you'll just need to use this.modelFor('program') I'm the projects route...

Comment: @kingpin2k Ok, I made an edit to add the code. The other problem I can see myself encountering is my form does validations so you can't submit it unless the object will be valid, but my model validates the presence of program. Will I have to take off that validation so the form can be submitted?